# Getting and error saying "unfortunately, Google Play store has stopped" ..please anyone help

Tags: google-play-store, 5.1-lollipop

I have done everything I could do -

1. Reset app preferences
2. Clear data/cache and uninstalled updates
3. Remove google accounts
4. And even Factory Reset.

But its still not working.

[image]

I have a Coolpad note 3, with Lollipop.

Comment: if you have a custom recovery installed you could try flashing a Gapps zip

Comment: Or simply flash your phone with a stock firmware. You may have been hit by malwares